# How to deal with multiple address layouts

Tags: design, mobile-application, signup-signon

I am facing a small UX obstacle, that is related on how to handle address layouts for different countries. We are building basically a sign up process, that asks the user to enter their country of residence. On the next step the user then has to enter their address details. 
The input fields on this page need to adjust to the standard address layout for the users country of residence.

Is there a smart way to design a uniform address layout that feels natural for users basically anywhere on earth? (Street, No., Zip Code, City)

Answer (score 1):

GDS have advice based on substantial amounts of user research:

https://design-system.service.gov.uk/patterns/addresses/?_sm_au_=iHVfFq7Wnfr61T2r

https://github.com/alphagov/govuk-design-system-backlog/issues/31

The short answer: there's no magic bullet.

You can use lookup for when a majority of users come from one country; or 'multi text box' which supports addresses from a majority of countries or a text area if you don't need the address extracted into sub objects.

It's an ongoing problem, and one with no simple answer. But knowing where *most* of your users come from will really help.